# Appropriate data structure for matching grouping symbols?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was supposed to write a program that takes as input an arithmetic expression. The program outputs whether the expression contains matching grouping symbols, and if it’s balanced it will calculate the expression result.

For example, the arithmetic expression 
 `{25 + (3 – 6) * 8}`  is balanced and its result equals  `1`.

`7 + 8 * 2` is balanced and its result equals `23`.

However, the expression `5 + {(13 + 7) / 8 - 2 * 9` does not contain matching grouping symbols, so we will not compute its result.

What is the best data structure (linked list, stack, etc) to use?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Use stack. The last opened parenthesis should be the first to be closed.

Start from left to right for the expression.

Keep pushing opening parenthesis onto the stack.

When you find a closing parenthesis, check if it is equal to the top of the stack (last opened should be first closed), if yes, then pop it out. If not then the expression is not balanced.

If the stack is empty at the end, the expression is balanced.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
```

#include

using namespace std;

int main(){

string str;

cout<<"Enter a String: ";

std::getline (std::cin,str);

bool flag=true;

stack st;

for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){

if( (str.at(i)>='0' && str.at(i)<='9') || str.at(i)=='+' || str.at(i)=='-' || str.at(i)=='/'|| str.at(i)=='*' || str.at(i)==' ' ){

// cout<<str.at(i) <<"came"<<endl;

continue;

}

if( str.at(i)=='{' || str.at(i)=='(' ){

st.push(str.at(i));

}

else if(!st.empty() &&((st.top() == '{' && str.at(i) == '}') || (st.top() == '(' && str.at(i) == ')')))

st.pop();

else{

flag=false;

break;

}

}

if(!st.empty()){

cout<<"Does not match"<<"\n";

}else{

if(flag)

cout<<"Match"<<"\n";

else

cout<<"Does not match"<<"\n";

}

return 0;

}

Comment: Please check how to format code, and also add some explanation.